# Subsetting data table based on patterns in data

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a data table like this:

```
z
     a   b negflag
 1:  1  41       0
 2:  2  61       0
 3:  3 623       0
 4:  4 -12       1
 5:  5  10       0
 6:  6  15       0
 7:  7  16       0
 8:  8  -9       1
 9:  9  31       0
10: 10  10       0
```

What I want to do is add a column next to "negflag", which tells me if there has been a positive value in the b column, 2 rows previously.

Like such:

```
     a   b negflag posflag
 1:  1  41       0       0
 2:  2  61       0       1
 3:  3 623       0       1
 4:  4 -12       1       0
 5:  5  10       0       0
 6:  6  15       0       1
 7:  7  16       0       1
 8:  8  -9       1       0
 9:  9  31       0       0
10: 10  10       0       0
```

So I want another column to give a 1 if there was a positive value 1 and 2 rows (inclusive) before the negative occurred.

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't the last value be 1?

Comment: I'm only concerned if it occurs 1 or two rows before the negative in column b.

Comment: So where exactly is the sub-setting happening? Also in your example you  first state :"if there has been a positive value in the b column, 2 rows previously.", then you state "give a 1 if there was a positive value 1 and 2 rows (inclusive) before the negative occurred." and in comment above you say "1 OR 2 rows before"...which one is it? If it is 1 OR 2 wouldn't all be 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first iteration of this answer didn't account for several cases which are not present in the provided dataset (though it did give the intended output on the provided data). With a new dataset, `znew`, you will need another procedure to get the correct output and thus meet the specified conditions in the question:

```
znew[, pf := as.integer(b < 0 & shift(b, fill = 0) > 0 & shift(b, n = 2L, fill = 0) > 0)
     ][, posflag := as.integer(shift(pf, type = 'lead', fill = 0)==1 | shift(pf, n = 2L, type = 'lead', fill = 0)==1)
       ][, pf := NULL]
```

or (based on the suggestion of @Frank):

```
idx <- znew[, .I[b < 0 & do.call(pmin, shift(b, 1:2, fill=0L)) > 0]]
znew[, posflag := 0L][c(idx-1L, idx-2L), posflag := 1L]
```

which both give:

```
> znew
     a   b negflag posflag
 1:  1 -41       1       0
 2:  2  61       0       1
 3:  3 623       0       1
 4:  4 -12       1       0
 5:  5  10       0       0
 6:  6 -15       1       0
 7:  7  16       0       0
 8:  8  -9       1       0
 9:  9  31       0       0
10: 10  10       0       0
```

Both approaches determine first whether the conditions are met (two positive previous values for a negative value in column `b`) and create the `posflag` variable.

---

**Used data**:

```
znew <- fread('a  b  negflag
 1   -41     1
 2    61     0
 3   623     0
 4   -12     1
 5    10     0
 6   -15     1
 7    16     0
 8    -9     1
 9    31     0
10    10     0')
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:** You can use the `shift` function from `data.table` as follows:

```
z[, posflag := as.integer(b > 0 & shift(b) > 0 & (shift(b, type = 'lead', 
           fill = 0) < 0 | shift(b, n = 2L, type = 'lead', fill = 0) < 0))]
```

will give you:

```
> z
     a   b negflag posflag
 1:  1  41       0       0
 2:  2  61       0       1
 3:  3 623       0       1
 4:  4 -12       1       0
 5:  5  10       0       0
 6:  6  15       0       1
 7:  7  16       0       1
 8:  8  -9       1       0
 9:  9  31       0       0
10: 10  10       0       0
```

Comment: could be eventually optimised to single `shift` call inside `{` when [data.table#1708](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1708) implemented

Comment: @jangorecki that would be nice!